# How to resolve "Domain shares an MX record (mx2.zoho.com) for a mail exchange which will not accept mail to the administrator"

Tags: email-server, spam

I have found one of our domains on a spam list, http://rfc-clueless.org/.
It states that:

> RFC2 is not a spam list. Each of our curated lists track compliance with specific requirements of RFCs (with the exception of the elitist list).

However, I'm concerned that some spam filters might consider it as a spam list anyway, since we occasionally have some problems with an email getting flagged as spam. So far I haven't been able to find the domain in question anywhere else.

Anyways, the comment for the inclusion on the list is:

> Domain shares an MX record (mx2.zoho.com) for a mail exchange which will not accept mail to the administrator.

Mail is hosted at Zoho, but what does it mean?

Is it something Zoho is the cause of, or is it something I can resolve myself?

Answer (score 0):

This means your domain shares an MX record (mx2.zoho.com) for a mail exchange which will not accept mail to the administrator.

It's quite clear what this means from the rfc-clueless site:

1. Your domain shares an MX record (mx2.zoho.com)
2. mx2.zoho.com is not RFC complaint
3. Because it does not accept mail to the administrator.

The "Listing policy" and "frequently asked questions" link on the domain page explains these and what to do about them:

http://rfc-clueless.org/lookup/mx2.zoho.com

Comment: I'm getting the same message from GMail. I would be surprised if they are non-rfc compliant. Could it be the SOA important person is invalid? Or the postmaster account isn't configured?

Comment: clueless doesn't seem to care that gmail is one of the biggest email and domain providers and are able to arbitrarily blacklist any such associated domain on a whim due to some relatively minor rfc non-compliance issue like this